# SPFx Custom Property Pane save property save

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, sharepoint-framework

When building a SharePoint Framework web part - How to Save Custom Property Pane value? 
I have created a multiselect field for Property Pane, but not able to retain the values when refresh the page.
In couple of links its mentioned to save the value in Host Webpart, what does that mean - Saving back in SharePoint ?

Comment: The value should be saved by simply assigning it to a web part property. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: I have 2 fields in Property Pane: 1) Dropdown to load all List Names in the web and 2) a cascade custom field to show all the fields within that list. Used https://cdnjs.com/libraries/multiple-select for Multiselect the field, but its not saving those value in the targetProperty. I tried saving it by custom button click and calling onPropertyPaneFieldChanged to save new values, but its not working. Is it possible to save values of a property pane field via code ? So, that I can get property values after refresh of Workbench ....

Comment: I have added PropertyPane code [here](https://github.com/get2pallav/React-SPMultSelect/tree/master/src/controls/PropertyPaneControls/PropertyPaneMultiSelect) and webpart : [Webpart](https://github.com/get2pallav/React-SPMultSelect/blob/master/src/webparts/spListRender/SpListRenderWebPart.ts)

Comment: How do you know that the property value is not being stored? Could it be that it is being stored correctly and is just not being displayed in the control?

Comment: Value was getting stored and rendered properly till I don't refresh the Workbench.

It seems I have found the reason, I needed to set Parent targetProperty field as well as call OnPropertyChange from my Custom Control:
`code`
  this.props.properties[this.props.targetProperty] = newValue;
  this.props.onPropertyChange(this.props.targetProperty, oldValue, newValue);`code`

I was not doing the first statement, 
Thanks for the help in understanding !!